# Why does bind flatten the List?

Tags: functional-programming, bind, monads, flatmap

I wonder, you say that `flatMap` is monad's `bind` method. The bind method takes a function that maps monad's contained item to another monad. This is how

```
option.flatMap(item => another option (f(item)))
```

gives me another monad with `f(item)` inside. But, what does it mean applied to List? By strightforward extension, if you map every List item to a (list) monad, you get the whole list of lists. Why does `bind` flatten the outcome when applied to the list?

Comment: "*to another monad*" should read "…maps the contained item to a container of the same monad"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the `Option` monad's *bind* does not return an option of an option, the List monad's *bind* does not return a list of lists. This *joining* is the whole point of monads - they are more than mere functors:

```
// Functor m
fmap :: (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
// Monad m
bind :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b // not m (m b)!
```

In the case of lists, this is done by flattening them.